# Remove src from wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazyload images that are being retrieved using the following code:

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
'order'=>'ASC', 
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$images = get_posts( $args );
foreach($images as $image):
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'large');
endforeach;
?>
```

In order to use the lazy loader i need to add a data-src attribute to the img which I have done using the following code:

```
function alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079($attr) {
$attr['data-original'] = $attr['src'];
return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes',
'alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079');
```

This works well however, the images are still being loaded even when they are not in the viewport and this is because of the src tag still on the image I believe.

IS there any way to remove the src or replace it with the data-original instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` instead. It returns the image data without echoing it, making build your tag easier.

It would be something like this:

```
foreach($images as $image):
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'large');
    echo '<img src="" data-original="'.$img[0].'" width="'.$img[1].'" height="'.$img[2].'" >';
endforeach;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: A better solution is the one indicated in this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305202/change-wp-get-attachment-image-attributes-src-and-srcset-on-specific-custom-fi